# How to fix the situation of migrating commits made with core.autocrlf=true to a repository with core.autocrlf=false?

Tags: git, qt-creator, atlassian-sourcetree

I accidentally set **core.autocrlf=false** on my main computer's git respository and **core.autocrlf=true** on my laptop's git repository initially. I changed the setting but am having problems now. I am using SourceTree, Qt Creator, and git obviously. I am moving commits with new code from the laptop to the main computer with format-patch and am.

Using **git am** to apply the patches failed initially because of the **core.autocrlf** setting.

```
error: patch failed: backupjob.cpp:152
error: backupjob.cpp: patch does not apply
```

I then used **git am --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace** to migrate the patches made with **format-patch** to the main computer successfully. However now when I modify code on the main computer it sees all the previous code as still ending with LF not CRLF and thus sees all previous code as modified not just what I changed (see screenshot below for an example).

Am I interpreting this correctly? What's the best way to remedy this situation? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: As a general recommendation—not a specific fix for your specific situation—I say "never use `core.autocrlf` at all". Instead, use `.gitattributes` to set the desired in-worktree line endings, if you must have Git fuss with line endings.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why my IDE showed all modified lines as showing up again in git diff. I updated the project in the IDE after applying the patches with git am. The IDE automatically modified all LF line endings and replaced them with CRLF. Git then showed all lines as being modified again. I then committed with the new line endings and everything was as it should be. This is an alternate method of replacing line endings than using git renormalize. I like it better because it shows you which lines were modified instead of every single line with renormalize.